# android Listview Seleted Event

Tags: android, listview

I have created sample apps with 2 ListView. I have an issue in listview selected event. I want to bind data into second ListView when user clicked on first listview. I have extends 'Activity' in my Activity class. I also want to change my current list item with different color.

```
listviewCatagory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    arg1.setSelected(true);
                    TextView lblCatagory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblCatagory);
                    lblCatagory.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.White));
                    //Log.d("Selected Item", Integer.toString(arg2));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onItemClickListener` for listview. `onItemSelectedListener` is used for spinners

Answer (score 1):

Use `drawable` to provide selection color and other stuffs.

**item_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#666666" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

and use this inside your `custom layout` as follow.

Suppose your `custom layout` has `RelativeLayout` then

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selected">
```

Comment: thanks!chintan let me check this i have use this selector as android:state_selected instead of android:state_focused

Comment: Yes, there are also other options available. You can use as per your need. I just give an example how you can use `selector`. thanks.

Comment: Chintan i have tried to change my selector but it didn't work

Comment: have you any idea to select last selected item in listview

Comment: check this http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html. set `selector` to your `ListView` then.

Comment: You have already accepted answer. How can I give you more suggestion though you got your own answer? In my solution, you don't need to remember last selected object my friend. Think on it.